# Robust M-estimator of location and dispersion by hand in R

Tags: r, outliers, robust

I try to estimate a location and dispersion model with R, as described [Maronna et al (2006, pp. 56)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470010924.html). However, my estimate dispersion does not converge to the desired value. Do I have an error in the code?

[image]

The starting values are the median and the MADN, for the estimates of the location and dispersion, respectively.

\begin{equation}
MADN=\hat{\sigma}_{0}=k\cdot Median(|r_{k,i}-Median(r_{k,i})|), \qquad k\approx 1.4826
\end{equation}
The model is

\begin{equation}
x_{i}=\mu+\sigma \varepsilon_{i}, \qquad \varepsilon_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\end{equation}

The $\psi$-function is the bisquare (biweight) for the location parameter and $\rho-scale$ for the dispersion parameter.

The $\rho$-function for the location parameter is

\begin{equation}
\rho(r_{k,i})=\begin{cases} 1-\left[1-\left(\frac{r_{k,i}}{c}\right)^{2}\right]^{3} & \text{if}\quad |r_{k,i}|\leq c \\ 
1 & \text{it}\quad |r_{k,i}|>c \end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $\rho'(r_{k,i})=6\psi(r_{k,i})/c^{2}$ where
\begin{equation}
\psi(r_{k,i})=r_{k,i}\left[1-\left(\frac{r_{k,i}}{c}\right)^{2}\right]^{2}I(|r_{k,i}|\leq c)
\end{equation}
with c set out to achive some efficiency value, compared to the Maximum likelihood estimator for the normal distribution.

The weight function for the location parameter is
\begin{equation}
W_{1}(r_{k,i})=\begin{cases} \psi(r_{k,i})/r_{k,i} & \text{if}\quad r_{k,i}\neq 0 \\ 
\psi'(0) & \text{if}\quad r_{k,i}=0
\end{cases}  
\end{equation}

For the dispersion (scale) parameter, the rho function is the same for the location parameter, but with $c=1$. However, the weight function is

\begin{equation}
W_{2}(r_{k,i})=\begin{cases} 
\rho(r_{k,i})/r_{k,i}^{2} & \text{if}\quad r_{k,i}\neq 0 \\ 
\rho''(0) & \text{if}\quad r_{k,i}=0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In my opinion, the results must converge, to the true parameters $\mu=10$ and $\sigma=5$. Indeed, it is pretty close to mu, but not sigma.

p.d: I tried to consult on StackOverflow, it is about programming. However, they pointed me well, that to answer this question it is necessary to know the underlying theory.

```
    #set.seed(12345)
    n <- 100
    error<-rnorm(n,0,1)
    x <- 10+5*error

    # psi bisquare function
    psi_bisq <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2  # c in the text above 
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k,ind <- 1,ind <- 0)
      return(y*ind*(1-(y/k)^2)^2)
    }

    # derivative of the psi bisquare function
    psi_bisq_der <- function(y){
      k <- 2.2
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k,ind <- 1,ind <- 0)
      return(ind*(1-(y/k)^2)*(1-5*(y/k)^2))
    }

    #  rho_bisquare function for the dispersion (scale) parameter
    rho_bisq <- function(y){
      k <- 1
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k, sal <- 1-(1-(y/k)^2)^3, sal <- 1)
      return(sal)
    }

    # second derivative of the  rho_bisquare function 
    rho_bisq_der2 <- function(y){
      k <- 1
      ifelse(abs(y)<=k, sal <- 6*(1-(y/k)^2)*(1-5*(y/k)^2)/k^2, sal <- 0)
      return(sal)
    }

    # W1 weight function
    W <- function(dato){
      ifelse(dato==0, ww<-psi_bisq_der(0), ww<-psi_bisq(dato)/dato)
      return(ww)
    }

    # W2 weight function
    Wdis<-function(dato){
      ifelse(dato==0,ww<-rho_bisq_der2(0),ww<-rho_bisq(dato)/dato^2)
    }

    #======== Simultaneous estimator of location and dispersion 

    # Initial value for the dispersion parameter
    sigma_est_a <- median(abs(x-median(x)))/0.6745

    # Initial value for the location parameter
    mu_est_a <- median(x)

    epsilon <- .00001
    err1 <- epsilon*sigma_est_a
    err2<-epsilon
    error <- 1000
    error2<- 1000
    delta <- .9 # this value can vary? the text use 1 for the scale parameter
    iter<-0

    while((error>=err1) && (error2>=err2)){
      pesos_loc <- rep(0,n)
      pesos_dis <- rep(0,n)
      for(i in 1:n){
        r[i] <- (x[i]-mu_est_a)/sigma_est_a
        pesos_loc[i] <- W(r[i])
        pesos_dis[i]<-Wdis(r[i])
      }
      iter<-iter+1
      mu_est_n <-sum(pesos_loc*x)/sum(pesos_loc)
      sigma_est_n<-sqrt(((sigma_est_a^2)/(n*delta))*sum(pesos_dis*r^2))
      error <- abs(mu_est_n - mu_est_a)
      error2 <- abs(sigma_est_n/sigma_est_a -1)
      mu_est_a<-mu_est_n
      sigma_est_a<-sigma_est_n
    }
    sigma_est_a
    mu_est_a
```

Comment: Could you write the expressions for the functions you're coding algebraically? The quoted part of the book  doesn't include all the information, and it's not quite clear to me what the function for scale you're trying to implement should be. It might also help people answering if you give more details about what is happening with the scaled estimates (specifics of what you're getting, rather than vague description). Do you have (say) a plot of the estimates for location and scale with changing sample size or something like that which would show the problem?

Comment: One immediately obvious point, to someone who hasn't stared at the code for hours (been there, done that) is that in your while-loop `r` is defined as a scalar, but it should be a vector for the line `sigma_est_n<-sqrt(((sigma_est_a^2)/(n*delta))*sum(pesos_dis*r^2))` to work correctly.  This won't fix your problem but may get you closer.